# How to use multiple parameter in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, qr-code

i want to ask how can i add multiple parameters into my qr code generator function? i have created qr code generator and trying to add more parameter for picker, because i already created a date picker, but i don't know how to add more parameter in swiftui and i am new to swift.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var start = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $start, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            Generate(start: $start)
        }
    }
}

struct GenerateQRCode: View {
    @Binding var start: Date
        
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        let cont = CIContext()
        
        var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            return df
        }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start))
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Date)-> UIImage {     //<--here how to add integer parameter?
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start)
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")   //
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

i have try to add parameter in the code but didn't work i think i missed some part of the code to complete it

here is the part i want to do

```
func imageGenerate(start: Date, time: Int)-> UIImage {     //<--here how to add integer parameter?
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start)
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")   //
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
```

and it show error after i add another parameter

Comment: Please explain what your are trying to achieve. "Add parameters" is quite vague. Provide some examples and show what you have tried.

Comment: @HunterLion i Have edited and added example

Comment: What error are you getting when you add time: Int as a parameter?

Comment: @LucasChae actually not an error, I would like to combine them, such as when scan the qr code it will have a combination of string, time and int

Answer (score 0):

You need a JSON or some other recognized form of data transfer.

```
struct ComboQRView: View {
    @Binding var start: Date
    
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return df
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start: start, time: 1))
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    func imageGenerate(start: Date, time: Int) -> UIImage {
        do{
            let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start)
            //Create dictionary with parameters
            let params: [String : Any] = ["start": str, "time": time]
            //Get data by encoding to JSON
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options:.prettyPrinted)
            //See what the data looks like
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")   //
            if let qr = filter.outputImage {
                if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                    return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
                }
            }
            return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
        }catch{
            print(error)
            return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()

        }
    }
}
```

The `inputMessage` will look something like below with this code

```
{
  "start" : "09:07",
  "time" : 1
}
```